# Help wiring timed fan switch

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

So I got a new timed fan switch and decided to put it in. The old switch was a simple switch, and all it had going into it were two black wires. The switch box has three pairs of wires in it, white + black + copper, white + black + copper, and white + black + copper. Originally, all three whites were pigtailed together, the top right black went straight into the switch, and the top left and bottom right black were pig tailed together with a third wire which also went into the switch. (Both via the push holes.)

It was not ground, and there was no white connected.

The new switch has white, black, red, and green wires. I connected it up, but obviously did something wrong, because it doesn't work.

Here's what I've done:

[image: What I've done]

I connected the single black wire to the black wire on the switch. Connected the pigtailed wire off the two black wires to the red wire on the switch. Pig tailed the green wire with the copper ground wire. And cut off the original three-way pigtail of white wires to make a four-way pig tail of white wires with the switch.

So what did I do wrong? How is it supposed to be? (And just in case I've created a horrible fire hazard, I've turned off the power at the breaker until I figure this out.)

The new switch is a Tork D1060MW 120VAC 60Hz 15A General Purpose switch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've got the LINE and LOAD swapped.  I think the red wire from the switch, should go to the single black wire that was on the old switch.  I'd guess that the bundle of black wires is made up of the feeder, a feed to another branch, and the pigtail to the switch.

Comment: That was it. Switched them and it works.